# Development vs Production issue with Mysql boolean full-text searches that contain a period and trailing single digit number

Tags: mysql

Launched a new website and all the mysql settings from dev to production seem to match, however the below query returns one result on the dev and none on the production environment. The data and table structures are identical on both sides. This seems to happen on certain results that have a period and then a single trailing number. The search_index on both sides contain the search term `top24.1`.

The Development Server version: `5.6.45 MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

The Production Server Version = `AWS Aurora MySQL Server version: 5.6.10-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    `books`.*
FROM
    `books`
INNER JOIN search_index ON(
        search_index.model_name = 'books' AND search_index.model_id = `books`.id
    )
WHERE
    MATCH(
        search_index.name,
        search_index.contents
    ) AGAINST(
        '(+top24.+1*) ("top24.1")' IN BOOLEAN MODE
    ) AND search_index.contents LIKE '%top24.1%' AND `books`.`deleted` = '0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check minimum word length setting "ft_min_word_len" in the parameter group, It's by default 4, the thing is the period "." can be considered as a stop sentence and 1 as a new word so if you have ft_min_word_len more than one the "1" won't be 
indexed.

Comment: Yes, they are both set to 4. Just not sure why it works on the dev but not the production server if they both have ft_min_word_len as 4 and the same data.

Comment: can you let me know what you get if you searched for top24 without the ".1"

Comment: then I believe the issue is related to the . since its been considered as period and being excluded on search text